# Azure VMSS manualUpgrade via Terraform azapi

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm, virtual-machine-scale-set

I need to implement the following az-cli command using TF:

```bash
az vmss update-instances --resource-group GROUP --name VMSS
```

I tried to upgrade an existing VMSS to the [latest model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#how-to-bring-vms-up-to-date-with-the-latest-scale-set-model) using the TF [azapi provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Azure/azapi/latest/docs/resources/azapi_resource) using operation ["Manually updates instances to latest model of the Virtual Machine Scale Set"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations):

```
data "azurerm_resources" "aks_vmss" {
  resource_group_name = local.aks_internal_rg_name
  type                = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets"
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool.user
  ]
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "aks_vmss_az_agent" {
  count                        = length(data.azurerm_resources.aks_vmss.resources)
  virtual_machine_scale_set_id = data.azurerm_resources.aks_vmss.resources[count.index].id

  name                       = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
  type                       = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
  type_handler_version       = "1.25"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = "true"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks,
    azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspace
  ]
}
resource "azapi_resource_action" "aks_vmss_model_updrade" {
  type        = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/manualUpgrade@2023-03-01"
  count       = length(data.azurerm_resources.aks_vmss.resources)
  resource_id = data.azurerm_resources.aks_vmss.resources[count.index].id
  method      = "POST"

  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension.aks_vmss_az_agent]
  }
}
```

but getting the following error:

```
│ Error: `resource_id` and `type` are not matched, expect `type` to be Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets, but got Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/manualUpgrade
```

UPDATE:
another approach [change the updatePolicy of the VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets?pivots=deployment-language-terraform) did not work either:

```
resource "azapi_resource" "aks_vmss_model_updrade" {
  name      = "aks-vmss-model-upgrade"
  type      = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachines@2022-11-01"
  count     = length(data.azurerm_resources.aks_vmss.resources)
  parent_id = data.azurerm_resources.aks_vmss.resources[count.index].id
  body      = jsonencode({ properties = { upgradePolicy = { mode = "string" } } })

  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension.aks_vss_az_agent]
  }
}
```

```
│ Error: embedded schema validation failed: the `body` is invalid:
│ `properties.upgradePolicy` is not expected here. Do you mean `properties.storageProfile`?
│ `location` is required, but no definition was found
│  You can try to update `azapi` provider to the latest version or disable the validation using the feature flag `schema_validation_enabled = false` within the resource block
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to implement the following az-cli command using TF

Alternatively, you can use the `resource "null_resource"` block for executing `Az-Cli` commands in Terraform.

I have added **Az-cli** commands in the **Terraform** block to update the **VMSS** upgrade policy

**Terraform Code:**

```
resource  "null_resource"  "venkat_powershell"  {
provisioner  "local-exec"  {
command = <<EOF
az  vmss  update \
--resource-group  <Resource_Group_Name> \
--name  <VMSS_Name> \
--set  upgradePolicy.mode=Automatic
EOF
}
}
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Once the above **Terraform** code was run, the **VMSS** upgrade policy was updated successfully as below.

[image]

Reference: [local-exec Provisioner](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in that particular environment I don't have `az` tool installed.